# Extrude cylinder into complex shape

Tags: modifiers, extrude, snapping

I know this probably an easy thing, still learning basics of Blender. I have a 3D-scanned object and am trying to create a base for it. I've simplified the scanned mesh as much as I can without losing the important definition i need to keep.

I want to just extrude the top face of the cylinder so it snaps to the underneath complex shape of the scanned model and doesn't poke out of the top.

[image: 3d scanned mesh with gap and cylinder below it]

In Fusion360 I would use 'Extrude to object' to automatically snap the top face of the cylinder to the bottom faces of the scanned model. I just can't work this out right in blender.

The closest I've got is using the Snapping tool to 'Face nearest' but it still leaves weird holes and some created faces stuck up out of the top of the base and in general the mesh is a mess:
[image]

I need the model watertight to 3d print it. I've also tried boolean modifiers, but I struggle to get them to work with some of the 3D scanned meshes I have on both 'exact' and 'fast' solvers. I know it's something easy but I just keep making a mess.

Any kind advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-Selecting the outer edges of the bottom part of your 3D scan, extrude them downwards.

2-Keeping these selected, press S to scale, Z for the vertical axis, and type 0.

3-With the looptools add-on enabled, go to the looptools functions and select “Circle”.

4-Resize and rotate this new circle to your liking

5-Select the top edge of the cylinder, press ctrl+e and bridge edge loops.